# How to import images in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, compass

I used to use the Compass library for SASS (.scss) but in my current project I'm not. In Compass I would load images for sprites like so:

```
@import "../../../images/sprites/large/*.png";
```

But now when I do this it gives the following error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../images/sprites/large/*.png
```

I know SASS doesn't have built in support for sprites but I copied over the compass sprite functions to be able to use them independent of the rest of the library.

Any idea how to solve this issue? The path is correct and the images do exist at that location relative to the .scss file where the import is called. I'm assuming this happens because on Compass's config.rb file you can define the import paths but on plain SASS there is no config file to do this from...

Comment: change the path?

Comment: @DanWhite I tried that, I moved the images folder and put it in the same location as the scss file and updated the path `@import "images/sprites/large/*.png";`, still get the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you add files individually, without the `*`?

Comment: @TedWhitehead No I tried that also to test and same error.

Comment: I think this is going to be very difficult for people to help you debug on SO. If you are open to adding Node to your app, there are some great packages to help build sprites like https://www.npmjs.com/package/spritesmith